# aws cloudformation error: Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Using aws cloudformation commands `package` and `deploy` I'm trying to copy my local lambda function to s3 and deploy template.
But I have faced with a problem during deploying a stack.
An error occur:
`Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400`

Question:
When I zip the labmda function manually and copy it to s3 - it works. What wrong in my workflow or my template?

my code structure:

`./template/template.yaml`

`./template/lambda.py`

commands:

```
aws cloudformation package \
--template-file ./template.yaml \
--output-template-file ./output-template2.yaml \
--s3-bucket "vmv-template-2"

aws cloudformation deploy \
--template-file ./output-template2.yaml \
--stack-name audi2 \
--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

my template file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  lambdaFunctionName:
    Type: "String"
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"
    Default: "createS3Object"
Resources:
  LambdaCreateS3Object:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Description: Create s3 object and write content from request body
      FunctionName: !Ref "lambdaFunctionName"
      Code: ./lambda.py
      Timeout: 60
      Handler: lambda.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      MemorySize: 128
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                  - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                  - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                Effect: "Allow"
                Resource:
                  - !Sub "arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/${lambdaFunctionName}:*"
          PolicyName: "lambda"
        - PolicyName: getAndDeleteObjects
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - 's3:DeleteObject'
                  - 's3:PutObject'
                Resource: arn:aws:s3:::*
  lambdaLogGroup:
    Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub "/aws/lambda/${lambdaFunctionName}"
      RetentionInDays: 90
```

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, and your template and commands are ok. All work as intended.

Comment: What is you aws version? my is `aws-cli/2.0.33 Python/3.7.3 Linux/5.3.0-46-generic botocore/2.0.0dev37`

Comment: aws-cli/1.18.67 Python/3.8.3 Linux/5.6.16-1-MANJARO botocore/1.15.49

Comment: Oh wait. I tried again, now it failed, with the same error as yours.

Comment: file in s3 must be zipped, but it is not in my bucket, as I understand `package` command did not zip it, when I zip it manually - it works

Comment: In my case it is in S3. Under some random name `545010293e9f0209caa61564caa35586`, but this is orginal lambda.py renamed. not zipped.

Comment: In my case the same ...

Comment: Can you run the commands in the `./template` folder, rather then outside of it.

Comment: Intresting, when I run the commands outside of the `template` folder and provide path `--template-file ./template/template.yaml`, then it does not work. But when I run the commands inside template folder, and use `--template-file ./template.yaml` then it works.

Comment: yes, now it works, but why? now file in s3 bucket is zipped

Comment: Don't know. Maybe a bug? For now I can provide the answer with the findings if you don't mind. I also check docs if there is a mention of such behavior.

Comment: yes thanks, I will also try to find something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

I tried to verify the issue reported. What was found, was a rather intresting behavior of the `package` command.

Namely, when the `package` command is executed in the following way (**outside** of `template` folder):

```
aws cloudformation package \
  --template-file ./template/template.yaml \
  --output-template-file ./output-template2.yaml \
  --s3-bucket "vmv-template-2"
```

The uploaded object to S3 will be just a renamed `template.yaml` file. Then the **`deploy` command fails** as reported expecting a ZIP file.

However, when the  `package` command is executed **inside** `template` folder, then it works as expected, producing a ZIP in S3:

```
aws cloudformation package \
  --template-file ./template.yaml \
  --output-template-file ./output-template2.yaml \
  --s3-bucket "vmv-template-2"
```

After that, `deploy` command **succeeds**.

Comment: Probably worth checking if the paths are correct inside both zip files, given the error happens upon paths change.

The zip package [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) mentions the folder structure inside the zip file is critical.